# Do loops in Haskell

Tags: haskell

In Haskell when you use <- in a do loop on a list, does it return the whole list?

so:

```
        do
      //some code
         c <-[1..4]
        //some code
```

Would c be [1,2,3,4]?

Comment: [Haskell doesn't have loops](https://sarakhandaker.medium.com/how-to-code-with-no-loops-8ed815624aae). Methinks you still have yet to have your brain _violently upended_ by Haskell and its FP paradigm (don't worry, it happens to all of us at some point). (Oversimplification warning: Haskell doesn't describe *how* a program works, instead it describes *what* it does).

Comment: [The `do` keyword in Haskell describes a monad](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/do_notation) (which is a sequence of operations that is performed only once, which is why it's used for IO). It is entirely unrelated to C family language's `while/do` loops.

Comment: @Dai I mean, it's not entirely unrelated. `do {x <- [1..4]; pure (x + 1)}` evaluates to `[2,3,4,5]`. Lists are a monad, so you can loop with `do` if `m ~ []`.

Comment: Can you show the lines before `do`?

Comment: My favourite monad explanation is "programmable semicolons". This line only makes sense when you are using "list semicolons mode" (a.k.a. *the `List` monad*) which is a mode that runs the code separately on all the list elements.

Comment: @Dai every programming language describes what a program does, even assembly.

Comment: @user253751 Let me put it this way: SQL is to M, what Haskell is to JavaScript - or for a worse analogy using the US tax and employment code: imperitive languages are like having an employee, while programming in Haskell is like using a contractor: you can only legally dictate the fine details of an employees' work, not a contractor's. Similarly, you can legally program the fine details of a C program, but not a Haskell program.

Comment: `do` itself does not imply a monad. You can write `do { 2 + 1 }`, and it behaves *exactly* the same as `2 + 1`. Only when you have multiple "statements" in a `do` block do you start involving monadic operators like `>>` and `>>=`. `do a == a`, `do {a; b;} == a >> b`, `do { let ...; ...;} == let ... in ...`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Why ask us when you can ask an interpreter?

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 8.10.7: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loaded package environment from /home/tommd/.ghc/x86_64-linux-8.10.7/environments/default
iPrelude> import Debug.Trace
Prelude Debug.Trace> :{
Prelude Debug.Trace| do
Prelude Debug.Trace| c <- [1..4]
Prelude Debug.Trace| trace ("C is currently: " ++ show c) (return c)
Prelude Debug.Trace| :}
C is currently: 1
[1C is currently: 2
,2C is currently: 3
,3C is currently: 4
,4]
```

notice the output is interleaved with the trace messages, so you can see `c` takes the values of `1` through `4` one at a time in the list monad.

If that last part "in the list monad" wasn't immediately obvious then do not ignore it - that is a critical part in understanding this answer and how it can (and can not) be applied to your use of the Haskell language.